# Sort Order Calendar Overlay

Tags: sharepoint-calendar, sorting, overlay

Is there a way to change the order of the calendars when using multiple overlay calendars in SharePoint online. I'd like them to sort alphabetically.

Comment: great question. I asked this years ago